# Installed CiviCRM in Wordpress via ftp, but it doesn't appear in plugin directory

Tags: wordpress, php, installation

I have Wordpress 4.2.5 running, with PHP 5.4. I am installing CiviCRM 4.6.8. I followed the directions here: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/WordPress+Installation+Guide+for+CiviCRM+4.5#

Before installing I checked with my hosting provider that I had all the other specs listed on the page to install and their support person confirmed that I did, fwiw.

I downloaded the CiviCRM folder, then uploaded it via sftp into the wordpress plugins folder, after changing the permissions for that folder. I tried both writeable and executable permissions.

When I log in to my wordpress site with my administrator credentials CiviCRM does not appear in the plugins directory anywhere, or in the plugins editor dashboard.

I saw that Jetpack and Super Cache were incompatible with CiviCRM. I deactivated both, but no change.

Please help.

[image: Screenshot of file structure]

Comment: When you add plugins, assuming you're using MySQL, the table in your WP database wp_options should have 'civicrm/civicrm.php' in option_value where the option_name is _site_transient_update_plugins (if you can use PHPMyAdmin or whatever your host provides to look at your WP database).  After you uploaded CiviCRM in wp-content/plugins, in the civicrm folder do you see civicrm.php as well as the folders civicrm,includes, wp-cli etc.? Sorry if that is an obvious question. Civicrm folder perms can be 755 (owner read/write/exec, read/exec for others). Jetpack/Super Cache not likely issues.

Comment: I will check on these items in the wp database.

Comment: Have you tried installing any other plugin via FTP? Just to double check.

Comment: Hi Georgia, did you download the CiviCRM archive to (Mac/Windows?) and then use SFTP from the command line,  FileZilla, (and it was CiviCRM for WP as opposed to Drupal right?) Can you edit Civicrm.php from your host's CPanel and does it look like "<?php
/*
Plugin Name: CiviCRM
Description: CiviCRM - Growing and Sustaining Relationships
Version: 4.6
Author: CiviCRM LLC
Author URI: http://civicrm.org/"

Comment: As Andrei suggested, can you try another WP plugin? you had uploaded JetPack prior to CiviCRM, and that worked  In the comment above I meant to ask what OS you downloaded to and what FTP program you used.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue might be what Lesley is pointing out at the end of the comment, regarding the folder structure.
In order for WordPress to identify a plugin, the plugin shouldn't be in a sub-folder, it could have happened that depending on the zip/unzip software you have used to extract the plugin, the civicrm folder (inside your /wp-content/plugins folder) might look like:

- civicrm-4.6.8

  - civicrm

    - civicrm.php
    - uninstall.php
    - civicrm
    - includes
    - assets
    - ...

When it should look like:

- civicrm

  - civicrm.php
  - uninstall.php
  - civicrm
  - includes
  - assets
  - ...

Comment: Hi Georgia; instead of FTPing the uncompressed files from Civi, can you 1) remove the existing Civicrm folder and contents from your plugins dir, and 2) upload the .zip or .tar file to your host, and then untar or unzip it in place?

Comment: I asked my host provider to help out and take a look, here's their reply: 
Thanks for your reply. I did see the issue you are experiencing however
its difficult to tell why that is not showing up in your wordpress
dashboard. The installation files are in the correct location. I don't
see any issues with permissions on your files. I would recommend contact
the plugin developers to see if there are any other issues that may cause
that. Your server does have all the requirements. Its possible its a
small item with the install that is being overlooked.

Comment: Georgia, can you confirm that if you upload any other plugin (not CiviCRM) via ftp it does indeed show up in the plugins page? If uploading any other plugin doesn't work neither I believe it might be a file/directory ownership issue, but you'll have to try first uploading another plugin and also let us know what ftp client you are using and as many details as you can otherwise nobody will be able to help you.